# java.lang.NoSuchFieldException

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Our professor assigns us exercises through the  jarpeb sytsem (Java Randomised and Personalised Exercise Builder). So the variables names are random.

```
public class Eczema extends Thread {
    private int aurite;
    private int[] serlvulate;
    public Eczema(int[] serlvulate) {
        this.serlvulate = serlvulate;
    }
       public int getAurite () {
           return aurite;
       }

 @Override
public void run () {
     try {
         aurite = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      for (int i = 0; i < serlvulate.length; i++) {
           if (i < this.aurite) {
              this.aurite = i;
              sleep (1000);
           }
         }
     }      catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Found an Exception!");
            return;
       }
 }
}
public class Stub {
    public static int polytoky (int[]a, int[]b) throws InterruptedException {
        Eczema Eczema1 = new Eczema (a);
        Eczema Eczema2 = new Eczema (b);
        Eczema1.start();
        Eczema1.join();
        Eczema2.start();
        Eczema2.join();
        return Math.min (Eczema1.getAurite(), Eczema2.getAurite());
    }
}
```

I followed the instructions of the exercise but when I chech it on the cmd the following error occurs:

> Field servulate not found: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: servulate.

Any ideas how I fix it?

Comment: Post the full stacktrace and indicate the which line the line number in the stacktrace refers to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be accessing a field named `servulate` while the proper field name is `serlvulate`. Find the line where this happens and fix the spelling.